# Where does the "Supersymmetry" in Witten's proof of the Morse inequalities come from?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, supersymmetry, topology, superalgebra

Where does the "Supersymmetry" in Witten's proof of the Morse inequalities ([original paper](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/Morse%20Theory/Witten%20Morse%20Theory%20and%20Supersymmetry.pdf) and [outline of proof for mathematicians](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic255421.files/212b0820beamer.pdf)) come from? Hopefully someone can provide an intuitive understanding? I am a math student, so I do not have a very extensive knowledge of physics.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could link to a copy of the proof, or at least a description of it.

Comment: Related question on MO.SE: http://mathoverflow.net/q/212419/13917 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/212486/13917

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: It is the [wedge product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) $\wedge$ and the [exterior derivative/differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) $d$ (which squares to zero $d^2=0$) that give rise to [Grassmann-odd elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalgebra) and [supersymmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetric_quantum_mechanics).

More concretely, Ref. 1 first writes down a (non-relativistic) [SUSY algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry_algebra) ${\cal A}$

$$\tag{10} \{Q_1,Q_1\}_+~=~2H~=~\{Q_2,Q_2\}_+, \qquad \{Q_1,Q_2\}_+~=~0, $$

spanned by two Grassmann-odd elements $Q_i$ and one Grassmann-even element $H$,

$$\tag{9}  Q_1 ~:=~d+d^{\ast}, \qquad  Q_2 ~:=~i(d-d^{\ast}), 
\qquad H~:=~\Delta~=~\{d,d^{\ast}\}_+. $$

Here $d^{\ast}\equiv\delta $ is the codifferential (=adjoint of the exterior differential $d$) and $\Delta$ is the Laplace-de Rham operator on exterior forms.

The relevant SUSY algebra ${\cal A}_t$ is a twisted/conjugated version of eq. (9) and (10), where $d$ and $d^{\ast}$ are replaced with

$$\tag{11} d_t ~:=~ e^{-ht}de^{ht}, \qquad  
d_t^{\ast} ~=~ e^{ht}d^{\ast}e^{-ht},$$

respectively. Here $h$ is a (real-valued) Morse function, and $t\in\mathbb{R}$ a real parameter. See Ref. 1 for further details.

References:

1. E. Witten, *Supersymmetry and Morse theory,* [J. Diff, Geom.  17, (1982) 661](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supersymmetric+quantum+mechanics#Witten82); Chapter 2.

Comment: Related: [Igor Prokhorenkov's notes](http://faculty.tcu.edu/richardson/Seminars/MorseTheory_Igor.pdf) found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory).

Comment: More References: K. Hori, S. Katz, A. Klemm, R. Pandharipande, R. Thomas, C. Vafa, R. Vakil, and E. Zaslow, _Mirror Symmetry,_ 2003; Section 10.4. The pdf file is available [here](http://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01.pdf).